# ideavim intelliJ idea Ctrl+d does not work in run prompt

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

`Ctrl+d` does not work in run prompt, however `Ctrl+u` does work

All other `^E` `^Y` does work. In vim emulation, `^D` is set to vim and not IDE. I am on arch BTW.

Comment: Please check that Ctrl-D is not used as OS shortcut.

Comment: It works in the code editor. But only fails in run prompt.

Comment: Please report an issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM